# Event.LatLng returning undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get LatLng points as you move across a Google Map. I have added a `domListener` to my map, but when I try accessing the `event.latLng` it comes back undefined. When I try calling the function `addPointsToArray`, the variable `pnt` is always undefined.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0hd4x32k/1/)

My code is

```
<html>
    <body>

    <div>
       <button id="move-mode" onClick="moveMode()">Move</button>
       <button id="draw-mode" onClick="drawMode()">Draw</button>
    </div>
<script>

var map;
var points = [];
var modeType;
var bMouseDown;
var poly;

function moveMode() {
    //alert("Move Mode Clicked");
    modeType = 'move';
    if ("ontouchend" in document) {
        return;
    }
    var options = {
        draggable: true,
        panControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true
    };
    map.setOptions(options);
}

function drawMode() {
    //alert("Draw Mode Clicked");
    console.log("Draw Mode");
    modeType = 'draw';
    if ("ontouchend" in document) {
        return;
    }
    var options = {
        draggable: false,
        panControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false
    };
    map.setOptions(options);
} 

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.7150, -117.1625),
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,

        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
            mapTypeIds: [
                google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            ]
        }
    });

    bMouseDown = false;

    var polyOptions = {
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.45,
        editable: true
    };

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'mousedown', function (e) {
        //do it with the right mouse-button only
        if (e.button != 1 && modeType != "draw") {
            return;
        }

        bMouseDown = true;

        //the polygon
        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map, clickable: false
        });
        //move-listener
        var move = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (eventPoint) {
            poly.getPath().push(eventPoint.latLng);
            addPointsToArray(eventPoint.latLng);
        });
        //mouseup-listener
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'mouseup', function (e) {
            google.maps.event.removeListener(move);
            bMouseDown = false;
            arrayOfPoints.push(points);
            points = [];
            polylinesArray.push(poly);
            if (document.getElementById('overlay').value == 'Polygon') {
                var path = poly.getPath();
                poly.setMap(null);
                poly = new google.maps.Polygon({map: map, path: path});
                polylinesArray.push(poly);
            } else {
                polylinesArray.push(poly);
            }
        });

    });
}

function addPointsToArray(pnt) {
    if (bMouseDown == true && modeType == 'draw') {
        points.push(pnt);
        console.log(pnt);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to push onto up points array, `pnt` is always undefined.

I am brand new to javascript and the Google Maps api so any help would be grateful

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I added more code. Hopefully this helps

Comment: I still don't see the reported issue with [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d7cdsrsn/3/)

Comment: My apologies, I forgot about the buttons that actually allow you to draw on the map. I am pretty sure I have everything now

Comment: Where is your html map id defined?

Comment: Up at the top of my script tag. I just left it out when I was moving it over. Let me add the variables

Comment: Can you post you entire code on the fiddle please.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how to get the map to load but here is my entire code https://jsfiddle.net/0hd4x32k/

Comment: [I still don't see the reported error (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d7cdsrsn/5/) or the input with id="overlay" (`document.getElementById('overlay')`) with/in your posted code.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Added a link to a fiddle which displays the map (added an `<input>` with id="overlay" to clean up the errors.  Don't see event.latLng undefined anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't that described in the title.  eventPoint.latLng is always defined.  When you process the `arrayOfPoints` to display it in the text box, you are looking for a `.latitude` and `.longitude` property of a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).  Those don't exist, you need to use the documented `.lat()` and `.lng()` methods of the `google.maps.LatLng` object to get those values.

```
function createFarm() {
    document.getElementById('search-field').value = "";

    var xmlString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfPoints.length; ++i) {
        xmlString += '<Shape><Points>';

        var singleArrayOfPoints = arrayOfPoints[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < singleArrayOfPoints.length; ++j) {
            xmlString += "<Point><Latitude>" + singleArrayOfPoints[j].lat() + "</Latitude><Longitude>" +
                    singleArrayOfPoints[j].lng( + "</Longitude></Point>";
        }

        xmlString += "</Points></Shape>";
    }

    document.getElementById('search-field').value = xmlString;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0hd4x32k/2/)